# "The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL" - error

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am trying to post to user wall but I am receiving this error when when share window pops up:

```
The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL
```

Now, I made a proper Google search in hopes to find a solution, but the only one given was that I need to disable "Stream post URL security". I checked the advanced settings for my app and it is already set to disabled.

So, by having a few years of experience with development on Facebook, and by knowing how incredibly bad the communication between us developers and FB has been in the past, I'm highly doubtful that they will assist me on this. Although I have heard that feedback is better here on SO than the good old FB platform forums. Well, lets see if my only option is to set my hair on fire or that there might be a kind soul out there that can assist.

Answer (score 5):

This answer from the [WordPress forums via user Samuel Wood (Otto)](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-posts-links-must-direct-to-the-applications-connect-or-canvas-url#post-3285636) worked for me:

`Go to the Facebook App. Edit its settings. On the Advanced settings page, disable the "Stream post URL security" option.`

Comment: This saved my day.  Worth mentioning Facebook app in this respect does not mean the Facebook app on the phone but your Facebook app on server side. In my case it is used part of an Android app posting Facebook wall postings and in that case if the posting showed an URL not within the domain of the server side app itself the posting failed. But with Stream Post URL security off my URL (which links to an app on Google Play) was accepted. Thanks Justin.

Answer (score 2):

Did you generate the access token using the Graph explorer app on FB?
Make sure you select your app from the select box on the top-right.
It will be selected as Graph Explorer by default.

This error happens as the selected app would be Graph explorer and its canvas/site url is not pointing to your site.
Doing this fixed my problem; it may fix yours as well.

Answer (score 2):

With the new app interface, issue is solved by turning off the "Stream post URL security" in the "migration tab"

Answer (score 0):

you always have to use the same domain for linking as specified on the app's developer settings. Now you can have several tlds, and custom prefixes as well.

Answer (score -1):

For others experiencing this problem, I was able to resolve this by configuring the Facebook > App > Settings > App on Facebook > Canvas URL