# not able to post link and images to friends wall with facebook new sdk 3.11

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios7

I'm using facebook new sdk 3.11 for posting links and images to friends wall through fbwebdialog.I'm getting the following error when giving link parameter.(As in the screen shot below)

[image]

I'm using Xcode 5 and my code is below

```
NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TESTING PURPOSE", @"name",@"545268428900714",@"app_id",fid,@"to",@"http://www.google.com",@"link", nil];


[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil parameters:params1 handler:
 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"result ======%@",resultURL);
     if (error)
     {
         NSLog(@"error ======%@",error);
     }
     else
     {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
         {
             NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
         }
         else
         {
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
             }
             else
             {
                 // [FBSession.activeSession close];
                 //[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];


                 double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
                 dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                 dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){


                     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank You!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Post has been Posted to your friends wall!"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                     [alertView show];


                 });


             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

Comment: USE THIS=>AND +1
Did you generate the access token using the Graph explorer app on FB? Make sure you select your app from the select box on the top-right. It will be selected as Graph Explorer by default.

This error happens as the selected app would be Graph explorer and its canvas/site url is not pointing to your site. Doing this fixed my problem; it may fix yours as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens as the selected app would be Graph explorer and its canvas/site url is not pointing to your site.

This answer from the [WordPress forums via user Samuel Wood (Otto)](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-posts-links-must-direct-to-the-applications-connect-or-canvas-url#post-3285636) :

`Go to the Facebook App. Edit its settings. On the Advanced settings page, disable the "Stream post URL security" option.`

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9251738/1597744) SO question.