# PHP Facebook Feed with Photo (Graph API: 2.5)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i try to post a feed to my wall and link it with a photo (later to the wall of a fan page).

First i post a photo (it works).

I use following parameters for photo:

```
[endpoint] => /me/photos
[message] => my caption
[source] => URL of the Photo
[no_story] => true
```

Then i post a feed with the photo to my wall and an exception is thrown.

**Graph returned an error: Invalid parameter, code: 100**

I use following parameters for feed:

```
[endpoint] => /me/feed
[message] => My Message
[object_attachment] => The id of the photo
```

if i remove the parameter "object_attachment" it works. In the documentation it is a valid parameter.
I don't know what i am doing wrong.

The Line of the exception:

```
 switch ($code) {
            // Login status or token expired, revoked, or invalid
            case 100:
            case 102:
            case 190:
                return new static($response, new FacebookAuthenticationException($message, $code));
```

I use Graph API Version: 2.5
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#publish

**Solutions for my problem:**
When i use the Graph Explorer i get followed error:
*One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the Stream post URL security app setting. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/ to learn more about app settings related to security.*

At this Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194474/3303652 i found a solution. Go to the Facebook App. Edit its settings. On the Advanced settings page, disable the "Stream post URL security" option.

Comment: Are you definitely using version 2.5 of the SDK? Can you reproduce the issue on Graph Explorer with the same access token? If so I would submit this as a bug to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @HeyDarren Yes i use v2.5. I tried it with the same token in the graph explorer and it worked. But not with the php code. Is it necessary to extend the livetime of the token? I will recheck my code again.